# jquery onscroll smoothly replace div with video

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here's a query that a half hour on Google couldn't help me out with. I love jquery-images-ondemand... how possible would it be to modify something like that in the smoothest way possible to work with a video. Not as simple as it sounds I think:

I have an image at the bottom of the page, when a user scrolls to within 100px of the image it transitions to become a video (not sure how I'll embed / load that but that's for another day).

On scrolling elsewhere on the page the video could continue, stop or simply revert to the image.

Thoughts?

Comment: Many. Could you elaborate your scenario with the code you already have in place in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple function from here called `isScrolledIntoView`, used to check whether the element is in the viewport view:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var $window = $(window),
        docViewTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height(),
        elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
        elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

You can implement the function above like this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $('div.video').each(function() {
        // Change the div element into a video when reached the visible area
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this)) {
            $(this).replaceWith('<iframe class="video" src="' + $(this).data('video') + '"></iframe>');
        }
    });
});​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/vVaat/11/